# Why can't my JAX-WS service find the handler chain file?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I defined a HandlerChain in my endpoint implementation like so:

```
@WebService(name = "MyPort", endpointInterface = "com.my.package.structure.here.gen.MyPort", targetNamespace = "http://mynamespace.com")
@HandlerChain(file="handler/handlers.xml")
public class MyPortImpl implements MyPort {
```

My package structure looks like this:

```
com.my.package.structure.here
|-- MyPortImpl.java
|-- handler
|   |-- handlers.xml
```

**This code worked.** JAX-WS found the handler XML with its pointer to the Java handler class and executed the code correctly. At some point, it simply stopped working. I now see:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.UtilException: Could not find handler chain file handler/handlers.xml for class com.my.package.structure.here.MyPortImpl
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.HandlerAnnotationProcessor.getFileAsStream(HandlerAnnotationProcessor.java:215) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
```

To debug, I reverted to the initial commit of the handler code, which I know was working. **The exact same code no longer works.** What could possibly be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

handlers.xml was not being packaged into my JAR. Unclear how this ever worked in the first place.